# Checking the assertion of outputValid N cycles after the assertion of inputReady excluding the cycles when Enable is deasserted?

Tags: system-verilog, system-verilog-assertions

If there were no enable signal, inputReady ##N outputValid would do the job. But, how should I exclude the cycles when enable is deasserted? Is there a short solution?

Answer (score -1):

If you want to include only the portion when enable is asserted, you can just use a [repetition operation](http://www.project-veripage.com/sva_6.php). For example, if `N == 4`:

```
inputReady ##0 enable [*4] ##1 enable && outputValid;
// or
inputReady ##0 enable [*5] ##0 outputValid;
// or
inputReady && enable ##1 enable [*3] ##1 enable && outputValid;
```

The repetition is equivalent to `N-1` delays:

```
enable ##1 enable ##1 enable ##1 enable
```

If you're building an assertion to check if-this-then-that, you could use the simple form:

```
inputReady |-> enable [*5] ##0 outputValid;
```

These are all equivalent:

```
inputReady |-> enable [*4] ##1 enable && outputValid;
inputReady && enable |=> enable [*4] ##0 outputValid;
inputReady && enable |=> enable ##1 enable ##1 enable ##1 enable && outputValid;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I actually looked for the combination of the non-overlapped implication, i.e., |=>, and the non-consecutive repetition operator, i.e., [->]. I was able to find the second after seeing your answer.